# Terminology "local flow" in Do Carmo's Riemannian geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, definition

Just trying to understand the use of the term "local flow", and if it has some sort of physical counterpart.

> Let $X$ be a differentiable vector field on a differentiable manifold $M$, and let $p \in M$. Then there exist a neighborhood $U \subset M$ of $p$, an interval $(-\delta,\delta)$, $\delta > 0$ and a differentiable mapping $\varphi : (-\delta,\delta) \times U \to M$ such that the curve $t \to \varphi(t,q)$, $t\in (-\delta,\delta)$, $q \in U$, is the unique curve which satisfies
>   $$
> \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial t} = X(\varphi(t,q))
> $$
>   and $\varphi(0,q) = q$.
>   A curve $\alpha : (-\delta,\delta) \to M$ which satisfies $\alpha'(t) = X(\alpha(t))$ and $\alpha(0) = q$ is called a trajectory of the field $X$ that passes through $q$ for $t = 0$. The theorem above guarantees that for each point of a certain neighborhood there passes a unique trajectory of $X$ and that the mapping so obtained depends differentiably on $t$ and on the initial condition $q$. It is common to use the notation $\varphi_t(q) = \varphi(t,q)$ and call $\varphi_t : U \to M$ the *local flow* of $X$.

Apart from the rigorous discussion of the paragraph above, I was literally trying to understand the name "local flow". Is there a specific meaning behind this terminology? something which is very intuitive maybe.

Comment: Have you had a course in ODE theory? I like to picture the flow of a vector field from that context.

Comment: No, which picture? I'm actually looking for a very visual thing for this specific definition.

Answer (score 2):

Let me expand a bit the last sentence of omk's answer, since that's really the reason for the word "flow" in this situation.

Imagine the manifold $M$ as being the space occupied by some liquid. The liquid consists of molecules, but these are so tiny that we usually view the liquid as a continuous entity. Think of the vector field $X$ as telling how the molecules move. More precisely, for any point $m\in M$, a molecule at location $m$ moves with velocity $X(m)$. So $X$ describes the instantaneous motion of the liquid, and we might therefore call it the *instantaneous* flow.

We might want to describe the motion of the fluid for all times, not just instantaneously. That is, we might want to know where a molecule that is now at position $m$ will be after a time interval $t$. This would be a function $\phi(m,t)$ that could reasonably be called the *global* flow resulting from the instantaneous flow $X$. There is, however, a problem with this idea of a global flow: Unless we assume some restrictive hypotheses about $X$, the global flow may not exist. An easy but instructive example is to let $M$ be the real line and to define $X(m)=1+m^2$. A molecule that starts at position $0$ will be at position $\tan t$ after time $t$, so it will fall off the end of the manifold $\mathbb R$ at time $\pi/2$. That is $\phi(0,t)$ isn't defined for $t\geq\pi/2$.

What does exist is a little piece of the desired global flow $\phi$, namely $\phi(m,t)$ for $|t|$ smaller than some little $\delta>0$. And this $\delta$ can depend on $m$. What Do Carmo is saying is that, if you restrict $m$ to range over a sufficiently small region region $U\subseteq M$, then you can find a $\delta$ that works for all $m\in U$. So the flow function $\phi$ is well-defined on $U\times(-\delta,+\delta)$. Because it's just a little piece of the desired (but non-existent) global flow, i.e., because it's defined only locally, this $\phi$ is called a *local* flow.

Notice that there's actually something global about this flow, in that it can be defined near *any* given point in $M$. But it's definitely local with respect to the time parameter $t$, as the $1+m^2$ example shows, and this locality, measured by $\delta$, cannot in general be taken to be constant over the whole manifold $M$.

Answer (score 1):

We can think of the flow in the context of ODEs in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Fix $E$ open, $f\in C^1(E)$. For $x_0\in E,$ let $\varphi(t,x_0)$ denote a solution to $\dot{x}=f(x),\ x(0)=x_0$, defined on a maximal interval of existence. Then, we can define a one-parameter family $\varphi_t$ via $\varphi_t(x_0)=\varphi(t,x_0)$, which we call of the flow of the ODE.

This can be looked at in a few ways. First, we can fix an initial condition, in which case this defines a solution curve through $x_0$. So, for a fixed initial condition, the trajectory can be visualized as motion along a curve through your initial condition. You can also this of the initial condition as varying in a set $E'\subset E$, in which case the map $\varphi_t$ can be visualized as the motion of all of the points in $E'$ (think of a set being "transported"). A nice way to think about this is to view an ODE as describing the motion of a fluid, in which case a trajectory is the motion of a particle in the fluid, and the flow is the motion of the fluid itself.

Comment: Ok, but my question is more like "given $\varphi(t,q)$ what happens if I fix $q$ and what happens if I fix $t$". The best way I can think to understand this is to draw pictures in both cases. In one case I can see a trajectory (fixed $q$), I can't quite figure how to visualize the other case. It would be a vector field, but I can't really picture the "flow" bit from there

Comment: Sure. I covered fixing $q$ above. Let's say that we fix $t$, instead. Then, what we have is the value of the solution at a given time slice for any initial condition. So, it's where the set $E'$ is sent by the fluid (as I defined above) at a given moment in time.